# jQuery zoom in/out on complete div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my source code to implement zoom in, zoom out, original size and full screen. It is increasing only width and height of 'list' id but the whole content size is not effected. How to implement for whole content using jQuery. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y51s6j6z/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='tree'>
<li id="list">
  <div class='emplist'>
    <div class='deptRow'>
      <h3>Research & Development</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='detailsRow'>
      <div class='detailsCol'>
        <h3 class='empName'>Satayanarayana Rao</h3>
        <p class='subTitle'>Project Manager
          <br>Hyderabad</p>
      </div>
      <div class='imgCol'><img src='C:/Users/Reddy/Downloads/ragava.jpg' alt='abc' /></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='infoRow'>
      <div class='infoMore'>
        <p>more +5</p>
      </div>
      <div class='infoMore pull-right text-right R'><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs text-center">info
</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

</div>

<button id='btn_ZoomIn'>+</button>
<button id='btn_ZoomOut'>-</button>
<button id='btn_ZoomReset'>1:1</button>
<button id='btn_ZoomFull'>Full Screen</button>
```

jQuery:

```
var resetW = $('#list').width();
var resetH = $('#list').height();

var currentZoomW = resetW;
var currentZoomH = resetH;

$('#btn_ZoomReset').on('click', function(){

        $('#list').width(resetW);
        $('#list').height(resetH);

    });
//alert(currentZoom);
 $('#btn_ZoomOut').on('click', function(){
        currentZoomW = currentZoomW - 5;
        currentZoomH = currentZoomH - 5;

        $('#list').width(currentZoomW);
        $('#list').height(currentZoomH);

    });


  $('#btn_ZoomIn').on('click', function(){
        currentZoomW = currentZoomW + 5;
        currentZoomH = currentZoomH + 5;

        $('#list').width(currentZoomW);
        $('#list').height(currentZoomH);

    });
```

**CSS**

```
hr{color:#000;}
.tree{width:450px;height:300px;border:2px dotted #f00;}
#list{border:1px dashed #000;}

.emplist h3, .emplist p{padding:5px 0px 0px 5px !important;margin:0px !important;}
.emplist{
    width:360px !important;
    height: 160px !important;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:#333;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;    
    position:relative;   
    cursor:move;
    !top:50%;
    !left:50%;
}
.emplist:hover{box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;}
.deptRow, .detailsRow{border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;}
        .deptRow, .infoRow{
            width:100%;
            height:20%;
            float:left;
            font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif !important;
            color:#00aff0;
        }

        .detailsRow{
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            height:55%;
        }

        .detailsCol, .imgCol, .infoMore{float:left;height:100%;}
        .detailsCol{width:69%;}

        .imgCol{width:30%;}
        .imgCol img{border:1px solid #ccc;margin:5px;}

        .infoMore, .infoMoreR{width:50%;font-size:12px;}
        .infoMore p {
            padding-right: 20px;
            float:left;
         }

        .R a{margin:5px;}


        .empName{font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}
        .subTitle{
            !font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
            !text-align:right;
            padding-right:20px;
            font-weight:880px;          
            font-family: 'Dekko', cursive;}
```

Comment: set width  in **%**

Comment: What syntax is this?: `!top:50%;`  I don't recall any CSS properties prefixed with an exclamation: `!`

Comment: @zer00ne those two properties are commented.

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani font size should be increase along with width and height and there is also an image

Comment: @nani0077 In CSS, the only way to properly comment is `/*....*/`

Comment: topic is not css. JQUERY and zoom in zoom out effect

Comment: If zooming is the issue, CSS, HTML, and JS/jQ must be considered in assessing the problem at hand. But it looks like you know more about web development than I do so I'll just leave you to figure it out yourself. BTW your tags include CSS, but it sounds like you know everything already since you are dictating what should be considered and what shouldn't be considered. You are really smart, I am not capable of helping someone of your caliber.

Comment: check my answer below. its may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check snippet below.  its may help you. its working `zoom in` `zoom-out` with `text` `img`

```js
var resetW = $('.list').width();
    //var resetH = $('#list').height();


    var currentZoomW = resetW;
    //var currentZoomH = resetH;
    var originalSize = $('.emplist h3,div').css('font-size');

    $('#btn_ZoomReset').on('click', function(){
            
            $('.list').width(resetW);
            //$('.list').height(resetH);
            $('.emplist h3,div').css('font-size', originalSize);

        });
    //alert(currentZoom);
     $('#btn_ZoomOut').on('click', function(){
            currentZoomW = currentZoomW - 5;
            //currentZoomH = currentZoomH - 5;

            $('.list').width(currentZoomW);
            //$('#list').height(currentZoomH);
            var currentFontSize = $('.emplist h3,div').css('font-size');
            var currentSize = $('.emplist h3,div').css('font-size'); 
            var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*0.8;
            $('.emplist h3,div').css('font-size', currentSize);

        });
      
      
      $('#btn_ZoomIn').on('click', function(){
            currentZoomW = currentZoomW + 5;
           // currentZoomH = currentZoomH + 5;
            var currentSize = $('.emplist h3,div').css('font-size'); 
            var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.2;
            $('.emplist h3,div').css('font-size', currentSize);

            $('.list').width(currentZoomW);
            //$('#list').height(currentZoomH);

        });
```

```css
hr{color:#000;}
    .tree{width:450px;height:220px;border:2px dotted #f00; overflow:scroll}
    .list{border:1px dashed #000;margin-bottom:20px}

    .emplist h3, .emplist p{word-wrap: break-word;padding:5px 0px 0px 5px !important;margin:0px !important;}
    .emplist{
        width:100% !important;
     height:auto !important;
     border:1px solid #aaa;
     border-radius:5px;
     color:#333;
     transition: box-shadow 1s;    
        position:relative;   
        cursor:move;
        !top:50%;
        !left:50%;
    }
    .emplist:hover{box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;}
    .deptRow, .detailsRow{border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;}
      .deptRow, .infoRow{
       width:100%;
       
       float:left;
       font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif !important;
       color:#00aff0;
      }

      .detailsRow{
       float:left;
       width:100%;
      
      }

      .detailsCol, .imgCol, .infoMore{float:left;height:100%;}
      .detailsCol{width:69%;word-wrap: break-word;}

      .imgCol{width:30%;}
        img{}
      .imgCol img{border:1px solid #ccc;margin:5px;width:100%}

      .infoMore, .infoMoreR{width:50%;font-size:12px;}
            .infoMore p {
                padding-right: 20px;
                float:left;
             }

      .R a{margin:5px;}


      .empName{font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;}
      .subTitle{
       !font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
       !text-align:right;
       padding-right:20px;
       font-weight:880px;   
       font-family: 'Dekko', cursive;
          }
          .emplist:after,.detailsRow:after{
             content:""; 
            display:block; 
           
            clear:both;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tree'>
<li class="list">
  <div class='emplist'>
    <div class='deptRow'>
      <h3>Research & Development</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='detailsRow'>
      <div class='detailsCol'>
        <h3 class='empName'>Satayanarayana Rao</h3>
        <p class='subTitle'>Project Manager
          <br>Hyderabad</p>
      </div>
      <div class='imgCol'><img src='http://i59.tinypic.com/w8xik5.jpg' alt='abc' /></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='infoRow'>
      <div class='infoMore'>
        <p>more +5</p>
      </div>
      <div class='infoMore pull-right text-right R'><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs text-center">info
</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="list">
  <div class='emplist'>
    <div class='deptRow'>
      <h3>Research & Development</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='detailsRow'>
      <div class='detailsCol'>
        <h3 class='empName'>Satayanarayana Rao</h3>
        <p class='subTitle'>Project Manager
          <br>Hyderabad</p>
      </div>
      <div class='imgCol'><img src='http://i59.tinypic.com/w8xik5.jpg' alt='abc' /></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='infoRow'>
      <div class='infoMore'>
        <p>more +5</p>
      </div>
      <div class='infoMore pull-right text-right R'><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs text-center">info
</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="list">
  <div class='emplist'>
    <div class='deptRow'>
      <h3>Research & Development</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='detailsRow'>
      <div class='detailsCol'>
        <h3 class='empName'>Satayanarayana Rao</h3>
        <p class='subTitle'>Project Manager
          <br>Hyderabad</p>
      </div>
      <div class='imgCol'><img src='http://i59.tinypic.com/w8xik5.jpg' alt='abc' /></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class='infoRow'>
      <div class='infoMore'>
        <p>more +5</p>
      </div>
      <div class='infoMore pull-right text-right R'><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs text-center">info
</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

</div>

<button id='btn_ZoomIn'>+</button>
<button id='btn_ZoomOut'>-</button>
<button id='btn_ZoomReset'>1:1</button>
<button id='btn_ZoomFull'>Full Screen</button>
```

Comment: I have nested list elements with that div content. by applying 100% width to '.emplist' it is effecting to parents when child are expanded. can resolve this issue. Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y51s6j6z/7/

Comment: hi @Ayatullah Rahmani can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072550/jquery-expand-tree-view-upto-selected-node-level