# jQuery - Expand Tree View up to selected node level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to expand the tree view up to selected node level. But I am not getting any idea about this please can any one help me on this.

For example We clicked on 'Parent d' in 'Category list' then expand 'Tree View List' up to 'Parent d' level for more details check     **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/b6cL8btk/13/)**

**HTML**

```
<h3>
Category list
</h3>
```

When click on any li expand tree list up to selected level

```
<ul id='category'>
  <li li-id='1' id='1'>Parent 1</li>
  <li li-id='2' id='2'>Parent 2</li>
  <li li-id='3' id='3'>Parent 3</li>
  <li li-id='4' id='4'>Parent 4</li>
  <li li-id='5' id='5'>Parent c</li>
  <li li-id='6' id='6'>Parent d</li>
  <li li-id='7' id='7'>Parent a</li>
  <li li-id='8' id='8'>Parent b</li>
  <li li-id='9' id='9'>Parent e</li>
<li parent-id='5' li-id='10'>Parent x</li>
</ul>
```

Tree View List

```
<h3>
Node View
</h3>
<div class='tree'>
<ul id='ulCollapse'>
  <li parent-id='0' li-id='1'>Parent 1</li>
  <li parent-id='1' li-id='2'>Parent 2</li>
  <li parent-id='1' li-id='3'>Parent 3</li>
  <li parent-id='1' li-id='4'>Parent 4</li>
  <li parent-id='3' li-id='5'>Parent c</li>
  <li parent-id='3' li-id='6'>Parent d</li>
  <li parent-id='2' li-id='7'>Parent a</li>
  <li parent-id='4' li-id='8'>Parent b</li>
  <li parent-id='4' li-id='9'>Parent e</li>
<li parent-id='5' li-id='10'>Parent x</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//$('#ulCollapse li').hide();

$('ul li').click(function(){
    var nodeId = $(this).attr('li-id');
    alert(nodeId);
})

var $ul = $('ul');

$ul.find('li[parent-id]').each(function() {
  $ul.find('li[parent-id=' + $(this).attr('li-id') + ']')
    .wrapAll('<ul />')
    .parent()
    .appendTo(this)
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/b6cL8btk/13/)**

Comment: I'll take a look ASAP!

Comment: @TonySamperi upadted fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/b6cL8btk/12/ in this, it displaying all nodes but we need to display upto selected node level only

Comment: @TonySamperi did you checked it

Comment: it's `jQuery` **not** `Jquery` nor `JQUERY`

Comment: @nani0077 I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve...I don't understand why onload the tree view hasn't the nesting level.
Why you put references to the categories on the LI instead of creating one UL for each group...

Answer (score 1):

I am not a javascript developer but, tried to solve your problem, here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sLvv319t/)

```
var $ul = $('ul');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $ul.find('li[parent-id]').each(function() {
    $ul.find('li[parent-id=' + $(this).attr('li-id') + ']').wrapAll('<ul />').parent().appendTo(this) 
// not changed its your code still, but I need this only first time, so moved into document ready
  });
});
$('ul#category li').click(function() {
  $("#ulCollapse1").html(''); // I have created a new div section
  $("ul").removeAttr('class'); // remove active classes 
  var nodeId = $(this).attr('id');
  arrangeNodes(nodeId); 
  $("#ulCollapse1").html($(".active").parent().clone()); //get the marked elements first parent (which is 'li')
  $("#ulCollapse").hide(); // hide the main treeview
});

function arrangeNodes(item) {
  $ul.find('li[parent-id=' + item + ']').parent().closest("ul").addClass("active"); // find item and mark the first ul as active (selected)
}
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve.

But maybe *:lt()* is what you're looking for

**HTML**

```
<h3>
Category list
</h3>

<ul id='category'>
  <li li-id='1' id='1'>Parent 1</li>
  <li li-id='2' id='2'>Parent 2</li>
  <li li-id='3' id='3'>Parent 3</li>
  <li li-id='4' id='4'>Parent 4</li>
  <li li-id='5' id='5'>Parent c</li>
  <li li-id='6' id='6'>Parent d</li>
  <li li-id='7' id='7'>Parent a</li>
  <li li-id='8' id='8'>Parent b</li>
  <li li-id='9' id='9'>Parent e</li>
  <li li-id='10' id='10'>Parent x</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>

<h3>
Node View
</h3>
<div class='tree'>
  <ul id='ulCollapse'>
    <li parent-id='1'>
      <ul>
        <li>Parent 1</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li parent-id='2'>
      <ul>
        <li>Parent 2</li>
        <li>Parent 3</li>
        <li>Parent 4</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li parent-id='3'>
      <ul>
        <li>Parent c</li>
        <li>Parent d</li>
        <li>Parent a</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li parent-id='4'>
      <ul>
        <li>Parent b</li>
        <li>Parent e</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li parent-id='5'>
      <ul>
        <li>Parent x</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$cats = $("#category");
$tree = $("#ulCollapse");
$tree.children().hide();

$cats.on("click", "li", function() {
  var nodeId = $(this).attr('li-id');
  console.info("NODE ID: ", nodeId);
  $tree.children().hide();
  var maxEq = $tree.children("[parent-id='" + nodeId + "']").index();
  maxEq < 0 && (maxEq = 0);
  maxEq++; //LTE since :lte() doesn't exist
  console.info("MAX EQ: ", maxEq);
  $tree.children(":lt(" + maxEq + ")").show();
});
```

FIDDLE ==> https://jsfiddle.net/x45j4fx6/1/